# Define a variable in one function and access it in another

Tags: php, variables, drupal, scope

I am using Drupal and in my .module file I have two functions which are called as 'content' from hook_block_view, as this:

```
function modulename_block_view($block_name = '')

    {
        $block = array();
        global $form_st;

        switch($block_name){
            case 'first':
                $block['subject'] = t("files from ".$_SESSION['form_state1']['values']['appName']);
                $block['content'] = first_block_contents($block_name) ;
                return $block;
            break;

            case 'second':
                $block['subject'] = t("page view");
                $block['content'] = second_block_contents($block_name);

                return $block;
                break;
        }
```

So in 'first_block_contents()' function, there is one object defined. I need that same object with same info in it, to be accessible in 'second_block_contents()' function. There are many answers on similar questions but I couldn't find this particular qustion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's during the same request you can declare a static variable. Drupal 7 uses this many times. Check the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7) of the `drupal_static` function.

```
static $drupal_static_fast;
if (!isset($drupal_static_fast)) {
    $drupal_static_fast ['whatever'] = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__);
}
$whatever = &$drupal_static_fast ['whatever'];

switch($block_name){
    case 'first':
        $block['subject'] = t("files from ".$_SESSION['form_state1']['values']['appName']);
        $block['content'] = first_block_contents($block_name) ;

        // Set the static variable contents
        $whatever = "Your Value";

        return $block;
        break;

    case 'second':
        // Use the $whatever variable now

        $block['subject'] = t("page view");
        $block['content'] = second_block_contents($block_name);

        return $block;
        break;
    }
```

As an alternative you can use Drupal's cache system with [cache_get](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/function/cache_get/7) and [cache_set](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/function/cache_set/7).

Answer (score 0):

In order to be accessible inside the function a variable must be declared global. Example:

```
function first_block_contents() {
    global $aGlobalObject;
    $aGlobalObject = new StdClass();
    $aGlobalObject->val = 1;
}

function second_block_contents() {
    global $aGlobalObject;
    echo aGlobalObject->val; // will print "1"
}
```

Note that the function `first_block_contents()` must be called before `second_block_contents()` for the variable to be initialized.

Comment: This is what I tried at first, got me an "call to a member function on a non object" error. The variable was empty when called in second_block_contents() function.

Comment: That sounds like the second_block_contents() is called before first_block_contents(). Nothing in your code determines the order that the blocks are created.